# Does a software update affect data?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, updates

I recently bought an Android smartphone, Samsung Galaxy Core (Model GT-I8262), checked for updates to the software(4.1.2). The package files were downloaded and when it was about to install, it displayed the precautions to take, before installing the update.

After installation, would it erase the contacts stored in my sim card or any other data on my smartphone?

> ***Phone info:***

Manufacturer : Samsung

Model : GT-I8262

Android Version : 4.1.2

Comment: Generally, the answer here is *no - it will not affect your data*. I can say that this is probably the case for you with a high degree of confidence. However, if you want 100% certainty, it might help to include current information about your phone such as Manufacturer, Model Number, and, if you know it, Android Version.

Comment: *After* installation is rather unlikely, *during* might be. Honestly: that very much depends. Most minor updates will not do so, some major updates might require it. So the answer must be based on several facts, such as from which version to which other version, plus the update method chosen (which is mostly a vendor decision).

Comment: @Izzy Yes, it might me 'during' installation. Great points. Thanks.

Comment: I believe @Izzy is requesting information about your phone. It may be a good idea to edit your question and include more information. Like I mentioned in my comment as well, we can't say anything with certainty without more information.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't but make sure you perform backup's before updating.

Comment: how does this improve the existing answer? This does not add anything new

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't affect data.but it is safe to take backup of important data.you can also check the Q&A of Samsung upgrade.http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/FOTA/